# importxml to Google Sheets + hltv

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, import

I'm trying to bring data from players in **hltv** to Sheet with `importxml` but can't get it. I've discovered that there are multiple **div classes** in a row and inside them there are **spans** where the actual data is.

I have tried multiple ways to get either, the all the info together or one at a time, but I'm starting to get out options.

For example:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.hltv.org/stats/players/11893/ZywOo","//@class='Statistics-row'//@class='columns'")`

Also I have tried to get players from certain country in https://www.hltv.org/stats/players

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you try with the full `xpath`? There are extensions for grabbing the full `xpath` of an element in a web page. Can you try and post what results you get?

Comment: Hmm. I tried to but couldn't do it. Can you help?

Comment: It is a javascript loaded website. I don't think you can scrape data from the site using `importxml`. You might need to scrape it programmatically.

Comment: I don't think the issue isn't related to javascript. Data are displayed even if javascript is disabled. It's just GoogleSheet is blocked to download anything by the website.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to get it? Thanks. I don't even try then anymore.

Comment: @coder_needed you can scrape the data through Google apps script. After that you can put it in spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you have any Youtube / blog link how to do it?

Comment: @coder_needed pasted the code [here](https://jpst.it/2aQ9e). You can use Google Apps Script official documentation to understand the code and modify it for your requirements. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to [@Madhurjya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13338210/madhurjya) proposal. With [IMPORTFROMWEB](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) addon you can have :

[image: Stats]

XPaths used :

```
//div[@class="statistics"]//span[1]
//div[@class="statistics"]//span[2]
```

Formula :

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB(B1;B2:C2)
```

But also :

[image: Players]

Xpaths used :

```
//a[preceding-sibling::img[@alt="France"]]
//img[@alt="France"]/@alt
```

Formula :

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB(B1;B2:C2)
```

Note : number of requests are limited. Check the pricing or code your own GoogleAppScript.